# Fenchel conjugate of $\| \cdot \|_1$ and dual of logistic regression

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, logistic-regression

I am trying to replicate some results from

Koh, K., Kim, S. J., & Boyd, S. (2007). An interior-point method for large-scale l1-regularized logistic regression. Journal of Machine learning research, 8(Jul), 1519-1555.

The rewrite the problem of optimizing logistic regression with $\ell 1$ penalty as convex optimization problem with equality constraints.

What I am interested in is the dual function of this problem:

\begin{align}
\inf_{v,w,z} L(v,w,z,\theta) &= (1/m)\sum_{i=1}^{m}f(z_i-m\theta_iz_i)+\inf_{w}(\lambda ||w||_1+ \theta^{T} Aw) + \inf_{v} \theta^{T} b v \nonumber \\
& = \begin{cases}
-(1/m)\sum_{i=1}^{m}f^{*}(-m\theta_i) &\text{ } ||A^{T}\theta||_{\infty} \leq \lambda \text{,       } b^{T}\theta = 0\\
-\infty &\text{ otherwise },
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where w is the weight vector, v is the intercept vector, $\theta$ are the lagrange multipliers, A the data matrix and b is the vector of binary outcomes.

Now, $f^{*}$ is the conjugate of the logistic loss function:

\begin{equation}
f^{*}(y)= \sup_u(y^{T}u-f_(u))=
\begin{cases}
(-y)\log(-y)+(1+y)\log(1+y) &\text{ if } -1<y<0\\
0 &\text{ if } y = -1 \text{ or } y = 0\\
\infty &\text{ ontherwise }.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Specifically the last two terms of the dual are of interest:

\begin{equation}
\inf_{w}(\lambda ||w||_1+ \theta^{T} Aw)
\end{equation}

I understand that this term can be restated as the conjugate of the $||.||_1$ norm ([Fenchel conjugate of a norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658609/fenchel-conjugate-of-a-norm)), which is the $||.||_{\infty}$ norm, but **why is this a
constraint on the dual function**?

Also I dont understand how the last term of the dual $\inf_{v} \theta^{T} b v$ results in the solution
$b^{T}\theta = 0$

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Can you try to restate again?

Comment: Hi there, I think I got most of the answers by myself. The only thing that I don't understand is the very last part with the infimum over a linear function resulting in kind of the derivative.

Comment: Please include a link to the paper.

Comment: [Direct Link](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/l1_logistic_reg.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on $\inf_v \theta^Tbv$: Consider the case where $\theta^Tb= \alpha\neq 0$. Then since $v$ is defined over all $\mathbb{R}$ we can set it arbitrary large, and just keep the sign opposite to $\alpha$. This will mean the Lagrangian is unbounded. For that reason we define the feasible set of $L$ to be $\theta^Tb=b^T\theta=0$, and the the actual value of $\inf_v \theta^Tbv = 0$.