# Why does any dual optimal point provide a separating hyperplane between a point and its projection on a convex set?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, convex-geometry

On page 400, in chapter 8 (*Geometric Problems*) of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), there is a discussion on identifying a separating hyperplane between a point and its projection on a convex set.  He states that in norms other than the Euclidian norm, the hyperplane is found via Lagrangian duality.

The example is stated as follows. (Please pardon the spacing, still figuring out how to use mathjax)

1. 

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \Vert y\Vert\\ \text{subject to} & f_i (x) \le 0, \quad i =1,\dots,m\\ & Ax = b\\ & x_0 - x = y\end{array}$$

2. The Lagrangian of the problem is therefore stated as

$$ L(x,y,\lambda, \mu, \nu) = \Vert y \Vert + \sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_if_i(x)+\nu^T(Ax-b)+\mu^T(x_0-x-y)) $$

3. The Lagrangian dual function (which I believe would be the minimum value of the Lagrangian over y which we obtain by setting $\nabla_y L(x,y,\lambda,\mu,\nu) = 0$) is then stated as $$g(\lambda, \mu, \nu) \biggl\{inf_x(\sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_if_i(x)+\nu^T(Ax-b)+\mu^T(x_0-x))  \quad \Vert\mu\Vert_*\leq1
    $$
   or $-\infty$ otherwise.
4. The dual problem(the max of the dual function) is stated as follows.

$$ maximize\quad \mu^Tx_0+inf_x(\sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_if_i(x)+\nu^T(Ax-b)-\mu^Tx)$$
Subject to $$ \lambda \leq 0, \quad \Vert \mu \Vert_* \leq1$$

**Question** Why is it that if $ \Vert \mu \Vert_* \leq 1$,   $\Vert y \Vert = \mu^Ty$ at the infimum?  I'm assuming this is the case because the two terms appear to cancel out as we go from step 2 to step 3.  I assume I'm just missing something obvious but just trying to gain some intuition on this either geometrically or algebraically.  Thanks.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658609/fenchel-conjugate-of-a-norm

Comment: thanks! How come we can assume that $argmin_y L(x,y,\lambda,\nu, \mu) \leq 1$? If that were true wouldn't we have $ u^Ty \leq \Vert y \Vert $  I guess based on @Y.S. 's answer below we can assume that at optimality $\Vert u \Vert_* =1?$ Also this is a silly question but will  $\left\|\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|=1$ hold for all norms of y?

Comment: to get from 2 to 3 you use that $\inf_y \left\{ ||y|| - \mu^Ty \right\} = 0$ if $||\mu||_* \leq 1$

Comment: Oh i see thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your step 2, the optimality condition for minimizing over $y$ can be written as
$$
\mu \in \partial \|y\|
$$
where $\partial g(y)$ is the subdifferential of $g$ at $y$, and is defined by the set of supporting vectors, e.g.
$$
\partial g(y) = \{z : g(x)-g(y) - z^T(x-y) \geq 0,\forall x\}.
$$
I am going to now try to prove that $\partial \|y\| =  \{z : z^Ty = \|y\|,\; \|z\|_* \leq 1\}$. This is a property that I know is true, and you can find proofs of this  [for example here](https://angms.science/doc/CVX/SubdifferentialOfNorm.pdf). But for fun, I'll try to do it constructively, so the technique is more clear. But, if you want to just stop here, this property is enough to explain the dual condition on $\mu$.

Plugging in $g(y) = \|y\|$,
$$
\partial \|y\| = \{z : \|x\|-\|y\| \geq z^T(x-y),\forall x\}.
$$
We can think about the worst case $x$ by thinking of this as a two-player game between $x$ and $z$, and first considering the moves for $x$. In other words, we want to first minimize
$$
 \min_x\; \|x\|- \|y\| -z^T(x-y) \iff \min_x \; \|x\|-z^Tx.
$$
We can decompose $x = \xi \hat x$, where $\xi = \|x\|$ and $\hat x = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Then the problem  can be written as
$$
 \min_{\xi\geq 0} \;\min_{\hat x}\; \xi(1 -z^T\hat x)
$$
and it turns out that, if you limit $\|\hat x\| = 1$, then the term $z^T\hat x$ is maximized when $z^T\hat x = \|z\|_*\|x\|$ (it is aligned with respect to the norm). This settles the maximization of $\hat x$, and we have
$$
\max_z \; \min_{\xi\geq 0} \; \xi(1 -\|z\|_*)
$$
From here we see that if $\|z\|_*> 1$, then $\xi$ will play $+\infty$. In that case, $\|z\|_*$ will play something $\leq 1$, and $\xi$ will be forced to play 0.
Therefore, if we force $\|z\|_*\leq 1$, then the worst case $x$ will be 0.

Now we have reduced
$$
\partial \|y\| = \{z : \|z\|_* \leq 1, \; z^Ty \geq \|y\|\}.
$$
But since $z^Ty \leq \|z\|_*\|y\| \leq \|y\|$, this can only hold if either $\|z\|_* = 1$ or $\|y\| = 0$--hence, the generic statement $z^Ty = \|y\|$.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I don't know much at all and am still a bit confused.  To get the dual function we are minimizing the Lagrangian, which in this case means shrinking y.  So as y gets smaller is there an elementary property that guarantees  $ \mu^Ty/ \Vert y \Vert = \Vert \mu \Vert_* $?  Since y is both in the numerator and denominator couldn't $ \mu^Ty/ \Vert y \Vert $ actually get smaller depending on the norm? Also Is there a geometric intuition here as to why $\Vert \mu \Vert_*$ would have to equal 1 for optimality to hold?

Comment: Yeah I realized my last post was drastically too vague, so I added some detail. Let me know if there are still confusions.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for taking the time to write out this explanation.  Sorry it's taken me some time to work through your answer.  I am still a little bit confused.  If $\|x\|-\|y\| \geq z^T(x-y)$ and $z^T(x-y) \leq \|x-y\|\|z\|_*$. I don’t quite understand why it follows that  $\|x\|-\|y\| \geq \|z\|_*\|x-y\|$ ?

Comment: So you should think of this as a two-player game between $x$ and $z$. $x$ is trying to violate the inequality as much as possible. So it will use its angle with $z$ to force $z^T(x-y) = \|x-y\|\|z\|_*$ (because that's the largest we can make $z^T(x-y)$.) Now assume $\|z\|_* > 1$. Then $(x-y)^Tz = \|x-y\|\|z\|_* > \|x-y\|\geq \|x\|-\|y\|$, which is a violation. Therefore it must be that $\|z\|_* \leq 1$.

Comment: So I can see that it's not that obvious why this is a sufficient condition, although it is definitely necessary. For that part... I know the result is right, but yeah proof is still not quite clear.

Comment: Yeah ok I think the proof is not right... sorry! let's try it again.

Comment: Yeah my problem was I assumed $x$ would try to play to maximize $z^T(x-y)$, but now that I think about it, it should play to maximize $z^Tx$ instead. Then $z$ deals with its issues against $y$ separately. I think this gets rid of the questionable triangle inequality step. (Anyway I'm certain the result is correct, just the proof is a bit creative on myside.)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to clarify and walk me through all that...it was very helpful to get a sense of how you're thinking about it.

Comment: Yeah it was a bit tricky in the end, but fun to play with. Glad it was helpful!